# Time complexity of adding node to LinkedList

Tags: data-structures

Is this O(n) or O(1)?

> Version: 5, id: 6114603: the worst-case time complexity of adding to a singly-linked list after the 10th node with a size of at least 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

> [What is] the worst-case time complexity of adding to a singly-linked list after the tenth node with a size of at least ten.

That *specific* task, adding an item *immediately* after node ten, is `O(1)`<sup>(a)</sup>.

That's because the time taken to do it is not affected by the list size at all. It takes the exact same time whether the list has ten nodes, or a hundred billion nodes, and could be implemented as per the following pseudo-code:

```py
def insert_after_tenth(first, item):
    tenth = first.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next # O(1)
    item.next = tenth.next                                     # O(1)
    tenth.next = item                                          # O(1)
```

I've calculated the `tenth` variable in that way (rather than a loop) to make it clear that the time cost is *not* dependent on the list size. And, since every line is `O(1)`, the complete operation is also `O(1)`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Admittedly, that's based on a certain *reading* of the question, inserting the new item *immediately* after node ten. There is another reading you could argue, that of inserting *at some point* after node ten.

However, if that were the case, all that extra stuff about node ten would be irrelevant, since it would be `O(n)` *regardless* of where you wanted to insert.

If you wanted extra marks (assuming this is some form of classwork), you may want to mention *both* possibilities but the first is by far the most likely.

Comment: Since it is asking for the worst-case time complexity, Shouldn't we consider the case where we add the node to last? (no tail pointer)

Comment: @ap0808: that wouldn't matter. Even if there was more work involved, that work would still be independent of the list size. Hence still `O(1)`. In any case, there probably isn't any more work involved (unless there *was* a tail pointer that needed updating). For a ten-node list, the tenth node would point to `null` and the pseudo-code in my answer (added recently) would still work.

Answer (score -1):

If a LinkedList has n node, where n > 10, then the worst-case time complexity is O(N) since it needs to iterate through the list to get the last Node.

Comment: While that's true for the general case of linked list processing, this *specific* case is O(1), as the number of nodes you need to iterate over is a constant ten. Hence it's not related to the size of the list.